# Pirámide poblacional

Tags: r

Intento obtener una pirámide poblacional pero no aparece.

Aquí está mi código

```
Pob_2005 <- read.csv("censo 2005.csv", header = TRUE)
Pob_t2005 <- data.frame(Hombres = Pob_2005$Hombres[-ncol(Pob_2005)], Mujeres = Pob_2005$Mujeres[-ncol(Pob_2005)], Edades = Pob_$Edades[-nrow(Pob_2005)])

pyramid(Pob_t2005, Llab = "Hombres", Rlab = "Mujeres", Clab = "Edades", AxisFM = "d", AxisBM = ",", Lcol = "Cyan", Rcol = "Pink", main = "Tlaxcala 2005" )
```

Lo único que aparece es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Bienvenido Andrea Cr a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta un ejemplo de tus datos, copia la salida de este comando `dput(head(Pob_t2005, 20))`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola Andrea debe tener un problema en alguna de las variables, posiblemente las edades. Para poder brindar una ayuda debe mostrar parte de sus datos o utilice `dplyr::glimpse(Pob_t2005)`, aquí le muestro la solución si sus datos siguen esta estructura.

```
library(pyramid)

Pob_t2005 <- data.frame(Hombres = c(34,19,11,11,8,7,5),
                        Mujeres = c(26,25,16,11,7,5,1), 
                        Edades = c('0-9','10-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-'))
Pob_t2005
  Hombres Mujeres Edades
1      34      26    0-9
2      19      25  10-19
3      11      16  20-29
4      11      11  30-39
5       8       7  40-49
6       7       5  50-59
7       5       1    60-

pyramid(Pob_t2005, Llab = "Hombres", Rlab = "Mujeres", Clab = "Edades", AxisFM = "d", 
        AxisBM = ",", Lcol = "Cyan", Rcol = "Pink", main = "Tlaxcala 2005" )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]